# Libre Office sometimes taking wrong characters

Tags: keyboard, libreoffice, text-editor

I'm using LibreOffice 6.2.2.2 on Ubuntu 18.10 since a week and on every document characters are sometimes lost or placed in the wrong way. By that I mean that as I type for example `linux` it will print `lnuix` at the screen although I pushed it the right way.

This occurs irregularly. I don't have necessarily a high CPU use when it occurs (sometimes around 30%).

Does someone know how to resolve this? For example, can one change the priority of keyboard input?

Comment: In your example, when you're typing linux, as you press each key, does the key print correctly then after a space or a return the word linux changes to lnuix? If so this sounds like an incorrect auto-correct.

Comment: It happens already before pressing space or return. Additionally, it happens without a recognizable pattern on different words and also numbers. So it's not auto-correct.